# Pivot add-on in cross-tab table Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot

Given the schema [here](https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial-ER.pdf) I wonder how I can use Pivot add-on to calculate a cross-tab table in the below format please?

```
Africa   America  Asia       Australia/Oceania   Europe     Total
#cities  #cities  #cities    #cities             #cities    #cities
```

The below script returns a normal result but I want it to appear in a cross-tab

```
SELECT  en.continent,count(ci.name)
FROM encompasses AS en 
INNER JOIN city AS ci ON en.country = ci.country 
GROUP BY en.continent
Union all
select 'Total', COUNT(ci.name)
from city AS ci;
```

The create/insert commands can be found here:

```
CREATE TABLE Country
(Name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 Code VARCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT CountryKey PRIMARY KEY,
 Capital VARCHAR(35),
 Province VARCHAR(35),
 Area NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CountryArea
   CHECK (Area >= 0),
 Population NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CountryPop
   CHECK (Population >= 0));

CREATE TABLE City
(Name VARCHAR(35),
 Country VARCHAR(4),
 Province VARCHAR(35),
 Population NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CityPop
   CHECK (Population >= 0),
 Longitude NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CityLon
   CHECK ((Longitude >= -180) AND (Longitude <= 180)) ,
 Latitude NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CityLat
   CHECK ((Latitude >= -90) AND (Latitude <= 90)) ,
 CONSTRAINT CityKey PRIMARY KEY (Name, Country, Province));

CREATE TABLE encompasses
(Country VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
 Continent VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Percentage NUMERIC,
   CHECK ((Percentage > 0) AND (Percentage <= 100)),
 CONSTRAINT EncompassesKey PRIMARY KEY (Country,Continent));


 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Albania','AL','Tirane','Albania',28750,3249136);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Greece','GR','Athens','Attiki',131940,10538594);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Macedonia','MK','Skopje','Macedonia',25333,2104035);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Serbia','SRB','Belgrade','Serbia',77474,7379339);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Montenegro','MNE','Podgorica','Montenegro',14026,672180);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Kosovo','KOS','Pristina','Kosovo',10887,1804838);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Andorra','AND','Andorra la Vella','Andorra',450,72766);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('France','F','Paris','Ile de France',547030,58317450);
 INSERT INTO country VALUES ('Spain','E','Madrid','Madrid',504750,39181114);


 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('LS','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('RM','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('MW','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('MOC','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('MS','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('MAYO','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('SD','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('REUN','Australia/Oceania',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('HELX','Australia/Oceania',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('STP','Africa',100);
 INSERT INTO encompasses VALUES ('SY','Africa',100);


INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Tirane','AL','Albania',192000,19.8,41.3);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Shkoder','AL','Albania',62000,19.2,42.2);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Durres','AL','Albania',60000,19.3,41.3);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Vlore','AL','Albania',56000,19.3,40.3);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Elbasan','AL','Albania',53000,20.1,41.1);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Korce','AL','Albania',52000,20.5,40.4);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Komotini','GR','Anatoliki Makedhonia kai Thraki',NULL,NULL,NULL);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Kavalla','GR','Anatoliki Makedhonia kai Thraki',56705,NULL,NULL);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Athens','GR','Attiki',885737,23.7167,37.9667);
 INSERT INTO city VALUES ('Piraeus','GR','Attiki',196389,NULL,NULL);
```

It the sample data it should only include 2 continents Africa and Australia/Oceania.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*caveats below*

## With `tablefunc`

First you need to add the [tablefunc extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

What you need is something like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  $$
    SELECT 0, coalesce(continent, 'Total'), count(city.name)
    FROM encompasses AS e
    JOIN country ON e.country = country.code
    JOIN city ON country.code = city.country
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((e.continent), ())
    ORDER BY 1, 2;
  $$,
  $$VALUES ('Africa'), ('America'), ('Asia'), ('Australia/Oceania'), ('Europe'), ('Total')$$
) AS t(rowid int, africa int, america int, asia int, australia_oceania int, europe int, total int);
```

Should get ya done.

Of course none of this works with the sample data because none of those countries have entires in `encompasses`,

```
INSERT INTO encompasses (country, continent) VALUES ('GR', 'Africa');

 rowid | africa | america | asia | australia_oceania | europe | total 
-------+--------+---------+------+-------------------+--------+-------
     0 |      4 |         |      |                   |        |     4
(1 row)
```

You may want to replace

```
$$VALUES ('Africa'), ('America'), ('Asia'), ('Australia/Oceania'), ('Europe')$$
```

with

```
$$ SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM encompasses ORDER BY 1; $$
```

But either way, you'll have to type that out in the table definition (the list in the `t(rowid int...)`)

## Caveats

I don't actually do this in my code, ever. This pivot is a waste of time and computation. I would always do this in whatever language I'm using to interact with the db. I don't actually think this is a good idea (here). But this is how it's done.